# simple incrementing of TCP sequence number and assigning it to sending tcp header acknowledgement number in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tun

[image]I am simulating TCP and now I am stuck to acknowledgement number handling.

`tcph->seq` is received sequence number and I am assigning it to tcp->ack_seq which is acknowledgement number  like

```
  tcp->ack_seq=htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);
```

But given the above code it seems like there is something inherently wrong, tcph->seq and tcph is in network byte order which It should be because I cast-ed it from buffer and assign to tcph pointer

This is my simple thread function that reads received buffer extract tcthdr (struct tcph) and tweak values or assign values to send tcphdr (struct tcp)

Its simply does what it does I there is really something wrong with this. I am keeping getting wrong acknowlegdemnet numbers (not really reflecting as to how I am incrementing sequence number and assign it to acknowledgement number). Can any one please take a look at this so I finally have TCP handshake successful. Problem comes I send SYN+ACK packet and my client retransmit SYN packet and this cycle is polluting my wireshark view nothing useful just awefull loots of SYN and reponse SYN+ACK from my code

```
void * receiver(void *data)
{



    //struct sockaddr_in cliaddr = {0};
    int recvlen = -1;
    int writelen = -1;
    //socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);

    while (!_do_exit)
    {
        //recvlen = rrecvfrom(_udp_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &clilen);
        char buf[VPN_MAX_MTU] = {0};
        char buf_1[VPN_MAX_MTU] = {0};
        memset(buf,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        memset(buf_1,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        memset(buf,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        memset(buf_1,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        

        char *str_source=malloc(18);
        char *str_dest=malloc(18);
        memset(str_source,0,18);
        memset(str_dest,0,18);
        recvlen=read(_tun_fd,buf,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        if(recvlen>0)
        {

    //BUFFER received here        
        struct iphdr *iph=(struct iphdr *)buf;  
        struct iphdr *ip=(struct iphdr *)buf_1;
        int y=0;
        for(int b=0;b<(sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr));b++)
        {
            if(y==20)
            {
                y=0;
                //printf("\n");
            }
            
            //printf("%x ",buf[b]<<24);
            
            
            y++;
        
        }
    //      tcph->check=(tcp_chksum(iph,tcph));
        //iph->check = csum(iph, sizeof(*iph));
        char str_src[18]={0};
        char str_dest_t[18]={0};
           
           
        //printf("IN %s %s\n",get_ip_str_1(iph->saddr,str_src),get_ip_str_1(iph->daddr,str_dest_t));
        memcpy(&ip->daddr,&iph->saddr,sizeof(uint32_t));
        memcpy(&ip->saddr,&iph->daddr,sizeof(uint32_t));
        //printf("OUT %s %s\n",get_ip_str_1(ip->saddr,str_src),get_ip_str_1(ip->daddr,str_dest_t));
        //Create ip
        
        //DOUBLE CHECK FOR BYTE ORDER
        
        //ip->tot_len=iph->tot_len;
        populate_ip_some(iph,ip);
        ip->tos=0;
        ip->tos=iph->tos;
        ip->ihl         = 5;
        ip->version     = 4;
        ip->tot_len     = htons(sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr));
        ip->protocol    = 6;
        ip->check=0; 
        //DOUBLE CHECK FOR BYTE ORDER
        ip->id=htons(100);
            ip->check = htons(csum(ip, sizeof(*ip)));


        //printf("before %d \n",htons(iph->check));
        iph->check=0; 
        //printf("middle %d\n",iph->check);
        //DOUBLE CHECK FOR BYTE ORDER
            iph->check = htons(csum(iph, sizeof(*iph)));

        int i=iph->ihl*4;
        struct tcphdr *tcph=(struct tcphdr *)(buf+i);
        //printf("tcp before %x\n",htons(tcph->check));
        tcph->check=0;
        printf("TCP START\n");
        tcph->check=(tcp_chksum(iph,tcph));
            printf("TCP END\n");
        //printf("tcp after %d\n",(tcph->check));
        //printf("i == %d\n",i);
        //POSSIBLY PRINT IPH for fun
        //for(int a=0;a<recvlen;a++)
            //printf("%x\n",buf[a]);
        //GET ihl SEND --  tcp
        int j=(ip->ihl*4);
        //printf("j == %d\n",j);
        int x=0;
        
        //SEEK filling
        struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcphdr *)(buf_1+20);
        //populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);//Do LOOK AT THIS FUNCTION TO [SEE/CORRECT IT] >:)
        seq++;
        if(tcph->syn==1)
        {
               printf("WHAT THE HELL THEN WHY\n");  
               printf("syn\n");
               //populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
               tcp->seq=htons(seq);

               //tcp->ack_seq=htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);
               printf("seq = %d | ack_seq = %d\n",ntohs(tcph->seq),ntohs(tcp->ack_seq));
               tcp->syn=1;
               tcp->ack=1;
               tcp->res1=0;
               tcp->res1=0;
               tcp->urg=0;
               tcp->psh=0;
               tcp->fin=0;
               tcp->doff=5;
               tcp->source=htons(80);
               tcp->dest=tcph->source;
               tcp->ack_seq=htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);//htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);
               
    //         printf("received tcp syn = %d\n",tcph->syn);
        }
        else if(tcph->syn==0 && tcph->ack==1){
                   printf("WHAT THE HELL THEN COOL\n"); 
               printf("syn\n");
             //  populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
               //tcp->seq=htons(1);
               tcp->seq=htons(seq);
               tcp->ack_seq=tcph->seq;
               tcp->syn=0;
               tcp->ack=1;
               tcp->res1=0;
               tcp->res1=0;
               tcp->urg=0;
               tcp->psh=0;
               tcp->fin=0;
               tcp->doff=5;
               tcp->source=htons(80);
                   tcp->dest=tcph->source;
               //tcp->ack_seq=tcph->seq;//htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);
                   tcp->ack_seq=htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);
        }
        else
        {
               populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
               tcp->syn=0;
               tcp->ack=1;
               //tcp->seq=htons(1);
               tcp->seq=htons(seq);
               tcp->res1=0;
               tcp->res1=0;
               tcp->urg=0;
               tcp->psh=0;
               tcp->fin=0;
               tcp->doff=5;
               
                   tcp->source=htons(80);
                   tcp->dest=tcph->source;
               tcp->ack_seq=htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);//tcp->ack_seq=tcph->seq;//htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);

    //         printf("sending tcp syn = %d ack = %d\n",tcp->syn,tcp->ack);
           
        }
        
        
        
        printf("syn=%d | ack = %d | fin = %d | %d seq = %d ack_seq = %d | urg = %d  | doff = %d | psh = %d rst = %d | rst2 = %d\n",tcp->syn,tcp->ack,tcp->fin,tcp->seq,tcp->ack_seq,tcp->urg,tcp->doff,tcp->psh,tcp->res1,tcp->res2);
        //populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
        tcp->dest=tcph->source;
        tcp->window=tcph->window;
        //
        //printf("%d %d SOURCE PORT \n",ntohs(tcph->source),ntohs(tcp->dest));
        
        tcp->source=htons(80);
        printf("%d %d PORTS \n",ntohs(tcp->source),ntohs(tcp->dest));
        tcp->check=0;
        //TCP CHECKSUM ABOUT TRIPPLE WOW
        tcp->check=htons(tcp_chksum(ip,tcp));
        
        //printf("tcpH = %d |  tcp = %d\n",tcph->check,htons(tcp->check));
        //IF needed make payload data
        //WRITE
        if (recvlen > 0) 
        {

            printf("\n-WOW WOW WOW received seq = %d  ack == %d",ntohs(tcph->seq),ntohs(tcp->ack_seq));

            writelen = write(_tun_fd, buf_1, sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr));
                    //exit(0);  
           // sleep(2);
            //debug("SR:%04d\n", recvlen);
            //debug("TW:%04d\n", writelen);
            
            if (writelen < 0) 
            {
            //debug("%s: rwrite() %s [%d]\n", _progname, strerror(errno), errno);
               //break;//NO NEED
            }
        }
        else if (recvlen < 0) 
        {
            //debug("%s: rrecvfrom() %s\n", _progname, strerror(errno));
               //break;//NO NEED
        }
        else if (recvlen == 0) 
        {
            //why
        }
    //FINALLY THEN SEND || DO WIRE SHARK 
        }
        
        // ...:)__ :) __:) ___:)___ (: __(:__ (;...  

    }

    debug("** Receiver ending.\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

**Update**

Now I am get TCP last segment not captured for my ACK+SYN packet

This is received SYN

```
0000   45 00 00 3c c5 18 40 00 40 06 e0 2f c0 a8 0a 14
0010   c0 a8 0a 0f bc b2 00 50 f0 32 1f de 00 00 00 00
0020   a0 02 fa f0 c6 93 00 00 02 04 05 b4 04 02 08 0a
0030   95 a6 8e 4d 00 00 00 00 01 03 03 07
```

This is SYN+ACK

```
0000   45 00 00 28 00 64 40 00 40 06 a4 f8 c0 a8 0a 0f
0010   c0 a8 0a 14 00 50 bc b2 86 e8 00 00 f0 32 1f df
0020   50 12 fa f0 cb 70 00 00
```

And this is SYN AGAIN

```
0000   45 00 00 3c c5 19 40 00 40 06 e0 2e c0 a8 0a 14
0010   c0 a8 0a 0f bc b2 00 50 f0 32 1f de 00 00 00 00
0020   a0 02 fa f0 c2 9c 00 00 02 04 05 b4 04 02 08 0a
0030   95 a6 92 44 00 00 00 00 01 03 03 07
```

ANd SYN again in row of this packet I get message  last segment not captured

```
0000   45 00 00 28 00 64 40 00 40 06 a4 f8 c0 a8 0a 0f
0010   c0 a8 0a 14 00 50 bc b2 86 e9 00 00 f0 32 1f df
0020   50 12 fa f0 cb 6f 00 00
```

This is my **Update 2** to this

SYN

```
0000   45 00 00 3c 9f 75 40 00 40 06 05 d3 c0 a8 0a 14
0010   c0 a8 0a 0f bc b8 00 50 55 a8 f4 2c 00 00 00 00
0020   a0 02 fa f0 83 25 00 00 02 04 05 b4 04 02 08 0a
0030   96 60 97 37 00 00 00 00 01 03 03 07
```

SYN + ACK

```
0000   45 00 00 28 00 64 40 00 40 06 a4 f8 c0 a8 0a 0f
0010   c0 a8 0a 14 00 50 bc b8 00 00 00 03 55 a8 f4 2d
0020   50 12 fa f0 18 8c 00 00
```

And this is SYN agian retramit

```
0000   45 00 00 3c 9f 76 40 00 40 06 05 d2 c0 a8 0a 14
0010   c0 a8 0a 0f bc b8 00 50 55 a8 f4 2c 00 00 00 00
0020   a0 02 fa f0 7f 38 00 00 02 04 05 b4 04 02 08 0a
0030   96 60 9b 24 00 00 00 00 01 03 03 07
```

Comment: oh, there are different funcitons for variables of different sizes: see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons)

Comment: @Effie do u mean I need to use ntohl and htonl for ack_seq and seq which takes unsigned int

Comment: is it 32 bits variable? then yes. (yes it is 32 bit variable)

Comment: @Effie its  uint32_t ack_seq; so yes

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of C programming, where integer variables have bit lengths and there are 10 different versions of how each bit length is called :)

Comment: @Effie now its saying about my server code next packet that `TCP previous segment not captured` in wireshark about SYN+ACK packet not captured

Comment: hm, what numbers does wireshark see?

Comment: did you change both calls to hton**l** and ntoh**l**?

Comment: i need to go buy food before the store closes, be back in a h. Wireshark tells you sequence numbers in normal decimal form, check that they match what they should be.

Comment: @Effie ok also this is last tcp packet that was not captured `0000   45 00 00 28 00 64 40 00 40 06 a4 f8 c0 a8 0a 0f   E..(.d@.@.......
0010   c0 a8 0a 14 00 50 bc b2 86 e8 00 00 f0 32 1f df   .....P.......2..
0020   50 12 fa f0 cb 70 00 00                           P....p..
`

Comment: I need both packets. Initial sequence numbers are supposed to be chosen randomly (which your client is definitelly doing!). How would I know if your ACK number is correct, if I don't see the sequence nummber that it is supposed to reflect to.

Comment: @Effie I have updated my question with all packets

Comment: @Effie now the problem seems to be this https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=why+tcp+syn+retransmission+happens I think my client is not getting SYN+ACK packet within time it use to wait. Do u know to increase ACK packet delay time in Linux

Comment: check the times betwee two syns and the time between a syn and your synack. Initial RTO is about 1 second, I doubt it takes you that much to answer. What does wireshark say about checksum?

Comment: @Effie ok also the checksums  are correct

Comment: I don't see something inherently wrong. But I am not wireshark and I do not parse TCP packets on a daily basis. I use tools, like wireshark, and I cannot see anything without it.

Comment: @Effie what if I have code I can share with u that, all of it. Can u please tell?

Comment: @Effie my seqeunce number for SYN+ACK packet is showing as raw seq in wireshark as `0000   00 00 00 03` but I am setting it zero. Do u why why. I believe if u reverse 32 bit zeros u still get zero

Comment: @Effie also important my SYN flag in request packet from client its raw sequence number in wireshare is `0000   f8 08 9d 5b` but in my response SYN+ACK acknowledgement number is `0000   f8 08 9d 5c`

Comment: this is seq_syn + 1, right?

Comment: i could probably tell something if you show me the trace. I can't do anything with the code unless i actually run it, and it is not that easy.

Comment: @Effie what u will find from trace what u like to know, I have added time by the time wireshark reads the packet at top of my question. just added

Comment: sorry, i do not see any reason why the packet is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sequence and ack numbers are 32-bit values:

Hence this line:

```
tcp->ack_seq=htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);//htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);
```

Is using htons/ntohs which are functions that swap the bytes of 16-bit integers.  You need to change it to use `htonl` and `ntohl`

That might not be your only bug.

Comment: yes I fixed this but now stuck at complete stupid behavior of linux connect function that its simply ignoring my entirely valid SYN+ACK packet. can u please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547975/tcp-socket-connect-function-ignoring-my-entirely-valid-synack-packets-is-there